# Firefox addon that tells you the css style used

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a firefox addon or is there a way to use firebug such that you can select some text on the website and it will tell you what styles are being used for that bit of text?

At the moment if I select a bit of text that is styled using css imported from elsewhere I would have to go digging manually to find out what style is being used.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just right click it in Firebug, choose HTML, and in the right pane, select Style>Show User Agent CSS. This will show a list of CSS rules that are being applied on the selected element.

Comment: oops, that style pane was squashed up to the right on my screen and I totally missed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Both [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) addons can be used for this.